# Swagger documentation generation for hybris Custom API

Tags: swagger, sap-commerce-cloud

Hi I have a custom Hybris API for which i want to generate the swagger documentation.the steps given @ https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/99783546e09949e2b4bf27795b889464.html are not clear and the static documentation generation fails to download the maven dependencies.

Can anyone provide me step by step process for generating this documentation

Comment: What exact Hybris version are you using?

Comment: We are using Hybris 6.7.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some libraries, change basesitefilter mapping, I try to explain below:

1. added jar files in your webservices extension lib folder:

> ```
> classmate-1.3.1.jar
> kxml2-2.1.8.jar
> spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
> spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
> springfox-core-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-schema-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-spi-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-spring-web-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-swagger-common-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-swagger-ui-2.6.0.jar
> springfox-swagger2-2.6.0.jar
> swagger-annotations-1.5.10.jar
> swagger-models-1.5.10.jar
> ```

2. Override this WebConfig Class

   @EnableSwagger2
   @Configuration
   @ImportResource({ "WEB-INF/config/v2/springmvc-v2-servlet.xml" })

   public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

   ```
   @Resource
   private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConvertersV2;

   @Resource
   private List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolversV2;

   private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

   @Override
   @Bean
   public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
       final CommerceHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new CommerceHandlerMapping("v2");
       handlerMapping.setOrder(0);
       handlerMapping.setDetectHandlerMethodsInAncestorContexts(true);
       handlerMapping.setInterceptors(getInterceptors());
       handlerMapping.setContentNegotiationManager(mvcContentNegotiationManager());
       return handlerMapping;
   }

   @Override
   protected void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(final List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {
       final ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();
       exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(mvcContentNegotiationManager());
       exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setMessageConverters(getMessageConverters());
       exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();

       exceptionResolvers.add(exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver);
       exceptionResolvers.addAll(exceptionResolversV2);
       exceptionResolvers.add(new ResponseStatusExceptionResolver());
       exceptionResolvers.add(new DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver());
   }

   @Override
   public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
       super.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
   }

   @Override
   public void configureContentNegotiation(final ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true);
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("**/swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }

   @Bean
   public Docket api() {
       final ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder().title("OCC API documentation")
               .description("This document contains the generated API documentation for Omni Commerce Connect v2.")
               .version("Version v2").build();

       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any()).paths(PathSelectors.any())
               .build().apiInfo(apiInfo);
   }
   ```

   }
3. You have to change basesite filter mapping in filter-config-v2-spring.xml file.

> ```
> <alias alias="baseSiteMatchingFilter" name="defaultBaseSiteMatchingFilter" />
> <bean id="defaultBaseSiteMatchingFilter" class="com.yourbasesite.webservices.v2.filter.BaseSiteMatchingFilter">
>     <property name="regexp" value="(?!.*swagger.*)(?!.*api-docs.*)^/([^(/)]+)" />
>      <property name="baseSiteService" ref="baseSiteService" />
> </bean>
> ```